# React Autocomplete selects value but posts empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-hooks, mern

I'm working on a React functional component that has a form.  In this form, the User can upload a photo and fill input fields to add a description.  The "title" input field is the only field where I am using the autocomplete feature.

The autocomplete feature works on the front end in that it renders a list of options.  It also populates with the selected option.

Issue:  When I submit the form, the input fields and values post just fine (and save to the db) except for the title field.

Below is the console.log of the response body.  As you can see, the title just returns and empty array.

{
 - writer: '5e8ef5a7c1f3264288316550',
 - title: [],
 - description: 'At Sheraton Hotel, 2019 event.',
 - images: [ 'uploads\1586702830965_IMG_8413.JPG' ],
 - List item

}
I followed Mosh's Autocomplete tutorial at this link [https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/.](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload'
import Axios from 'axios';
import Countrylist from "./CountriesList"


const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "Africa" },
    { key: 2, value: "Europe" },
    { key: 3, value: "Asia" },
    { key: 4, value: "North America" },
    { key: 5, value: "South America" },
    { key: 6, value: "Australia" },
    { key: 7, value: "Antarctica" }
]



function UploadProductPage(props) {

    const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState([])
    const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("")
    const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0)
    const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState(1)
    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])


    const updateCountry = (newCountry) => {
        setTitleValue(newCountry)
    }

    const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onPriceChange = (event) => {
        setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
        setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const updateImages = (newImages) => {
        setImages(newImages)
    }
    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();


        if (!TitleValue || !DescriptionValue || !PriceValue ||
            !ContinentValue || !Images) {
            return alert('fill all the fields first!')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: props.user.userData._id,
            title: TitleValue,
            description: DescriptionValue,
            price: PriceValue,
            images: Images,
            continents: ContinentValue,
        }

        Axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('Product Successfully Uploaded.  The Country is ' + variables.title)
                    props.history.push('/')
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload Product')
                }
            })

    }

    return (
        <div style={{
            maxWidth: '700px',
            margin: '2rem auto',
            padding: "10px",
            borderRadius: "10px",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)"
        }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2}> Upload New Photo</Title>
            </div>


            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>

                {/* DropZone */}
                <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />

                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Title </label>
                <Countrylist
                    onChange={updateCountry}
                    value={TitleValue}
                    onSelect={(value) => TitleValue = value}
                    name="title"
                />

                <br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <TextArea
                    onChange={onDescriptionChange}
                    value={DescriptionValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Year</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onPriceChange}
                    placeholder="Enter four digit year"
                    value={PriceValue}
                    type="number"
                />
                <br /><br />
                <select onChange={onContinentsSelectChange}>
                    {Continents.map(item => (
                        <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>{item.value} </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />

                <Button
                    onClick={onSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </Button>

            </Form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onSelect isn't changing the value of TitleValue.

I'm not sure if the value you're passing in is valid, make sure that you can console.log(value) and see that it is when you use onSelect.

```
    onSelect={(value) => TitleValue = value}
```

you should be using the Hook setTitleValue you initialized or that function that calls setTitleValue

```
    const updateCountry = (newCountry) => {
        setTitleValue(newCountry)
    }
```

```
    onSelect={value => {
       console.log(value)  //make sure you are getting the right data
       setTitleValue(value)
    }}
```

Your onChange also needs to deal with the event.target.value, so you would need to update updateCountry

```
    const updateCountry = e => {
        setTitleValue(e.target.value)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Queens Coder.  Thanks!  I edited my code to reflect your suggestions.  However, I’m still getting the same result.  I’m not too experienced with React but could it be that the CountryList component I’m using is a class component and I’m plugging it into a functional component?

Comment: Using a class component inside of functional component shouldn't matter assuming your components are rendering correctly. Try to console.log what you are getting where you are changing the title. That way you can see what is going on when the you attempt to change the title.